# Real time Email Checking in Database using PHP Codeigniter, Ajax and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to implement a realtime email duplication check in an application using PHP Codigniter, Ajax and Jquery. But I am not getting any successful results.

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#email").keyup(function()
 {
  if($("#email").val().length >= 4)
  { 
  $.ajax(
  {
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo site_url('stthomas/check_user');?>",
   data: "email="+$("#email").val(),
   success: function(msg)
   {
    if(msg=="true")
    { 
     $("#usr_verify").css({ "background-image": "url('<?php echo base_url();?>images/yes.png')" });
    }
    else
    { 
     $("#usr_verify").css({ "background-image": "url('<?php echo base_url();?>images/no.png')" });
    }
   }
  });
  }
  else 
  { 
   $("#usr_verify").css({ "background-image": "none" });
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

My Form is as Follows

```
<div class="form-group formgp">
              <label class="col-md-4"  for="Inputemail">Email :</label>
              <div class="col-md-8" >
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"  placeholder="Email"> <span id="usr_verify" class="verify"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function check_user()
{
 $usr=$this->input->post('email');
 $result=$this->stthomas_model->check_user_exist($usr);
 if($result)
 {
  echo "false";
  }
 else{
  echo "true";
  }
}
```

Model:

```
public function check_user_exist($usr)
{
 $this->db->where("email",$usr);
 $query=$this->db->get("email");
 if($query->num_rows()>0)
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get in console?

Comment: I am not getting any error messages. But it is not working....

Comment: there is no troubleshooting information. Inspect actual request for full details in browser console and report all findings. WHy do you need to check on every keyup for email?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to guess what the problem is, but you better check the jquery ajax error detail. you have just set the success part of process in your code:

```
success: function(msg){
```

See what error you have if the ajax gets an error:

```
success: function(msg){
    // success code
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
   var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
   alert(err.Message);
}
```